# Did I just get serial-upvoted?

Tags: support

I know that my title might be laughable but it just seems very odd that all those upvotes came in at once.

Was there a lag in the notification system?

[image]

Comment: Did all of them come in at exactly the same time, to the second? Could just be that you have a fan. :)

Comment: I'm not sure @Karan my profile only displays accuracy to the minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this happens sometimes. If it triggers the automated script, they'll be reversed. We don't know for sure what the algorithm is, so it may just stay like that. Enjoy your extra reputation :)

Comment: I can live with that, thanks!